# Python 3.4 - Using REGEX to Match a string and then copy the following line

Tags: python, regex

I have searched the FAQs and a few other REGEX sites but have not found an answer to my question.  While I can successfully execute the Match, I cannot figure out the best way to then reference the NEXT line after the match to print or add to a list, etc.  Here is my pogram

```
with open("input.txt", mode='r') as sourcefile, open("output.txt", mode='w') as destinationfile:
    for codeline in sourcefile:
        if (re.match("interface GigabitEthernet0/[0123]", codeline)):
            print(codeline)
```

My input file has the following...

input.txt

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 Ip Address 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0
```

When I execute this I get the following in return...

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
```

But I want to get this instead...

```
Ip Address 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0
```

I've figured out quite a bit on my own at this point, but this trivial challenge has been tripping me up.  How to I print the next line down from the iterator if it matches the regex sequence?

Thanks in advance if you can assist me.  Sorry, but this is my first post at Stack so if I am not formatting this correctly, I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a flag to print the following line as well

```
print_next = False
for codeline in sourcefile:
    if print_next:
        print(codeline)
        print_next = False
    elif (re.match("interface GigabitEthernet0/[0123]", codeline)):
        print_next = True
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try it out and check back momentarily!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the next() type to accomplish my goal.

Thank you.